# Iterate through files in a dictionary in numerical order

Tags: python

I have a a thousand files listed accordingly:

```
1_r.txt
2_r.txt
3_r.tet
...
999_r.txt
```

where r is a random alphanumeric of random length.
I need to iterate through the files in numerical order with python. 
I thought of using something like:

```
count = 1
for i in os.listdir():
    if i.startswith(str(count) + '_') == True:
        # do stuff 
        print(i)
```

However, the above method will not iterate through the dictionary. I thought of using the `sorted` method, however my files do not order by number alone.
Please help.

Comment: so, you want to get all filenames and sort them by number?

Comment: Essentially yes for this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a `key` which dictates that the sort is done by splitting on the `_` character and then sorting on the `int` form of the part left of the `_`:

```
filenames = os.listdir()
sorted_filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[0]))
```

Then simply loop over `sorted_filenames`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a lambda function to pass to the `key` parameter of `sorted` in order to sort the `list` the way that you need it sorted. The syntax is:

`sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: whatever you need done to x)`

Then iterate through the sorted list.